# Can't run MondoDB on a mounted disk

Tags: mongodb, permissions

While trying to run MongoDB on a mounted disk I found that its user (`mongodb`) has no permissions to the folder it's configured to (`/media/dutzi/hdd/mongodb`).

I then tried running:

```
sudo -H -u mongodb bash -c 'touch /media/dutzi/hdd/mongodb/asd'
```

And got:

```
touch: cannot touch '/media/dutzi/hdd/mongodb/asd': Permission denied
```

When trying with a different user (root, or my own) I was able to touch that file.

I tried (recursively) allowing all possible permissions, currently it looks like this:

```
❯ ll /media/dutzi/hdd/
total 20K
drwxrwxrwx 2 root    root     16K Nov  7 17:25 lost+found/
drwsrwsrwx 4 mongodb mongodb 4.0K Nov  7 17:38 mongodb/

dutzi in dutzipc in ~
❯ ll /media/dutzi/hdd/mongodb/
total 204K
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mongodb mongodb   47 Nov  7 17:29 WiredTiger*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mongodb mongodb   21 Nov  7 17:29 WiredTiger.lock*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mongodb mongodb 1.3K Nov  7 17:29 WiredTiger.turtle*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mongodb mongodb  44K Nov  7 17:29 WiredTiger.wt*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mongodb mongodb 4.0K Nov  7 17:29 WiredTigerHS.wt*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mongodb mongodb  20K Nov  7 17:29 _mdb_catalog.wt*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mongodb mongodb    0 Nov  7 17:31 as2d*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mongodb mongodb    0 Nov  7 17:38 asd*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mongodb mongodb  20K Nov  7 17:29 collection-0--7241342955860792272.wt*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mongodb mongodb  20K Nov  7 17:29 collection-2--7241342955860792272.wt*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mongodb mongodb 4.0K Nov  7 17:29 collection-4--7241342955860792272.wt*
drwxrwxrwx 2 mongodb mongodb 4.0K Nov  7 17:29 diagnostic.data/
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mongodb mongodb  20K Nov  7 17:29 index-1--7241342955860792272.wt*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mongodb mongodb  20K Nov  7 17:29 index-3--7241342955860792272.wt*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mongodb mongodb 4.0K Nov  7 17:29 index-5--7241342955860792272.wt*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mongodb mongodb 4.0K Nov  7 17:29 index-6--7241342955860792272.wt*
drwxrwxrwx 2 mongodb mongodb 4.0K Nov  7 17:29 journal/
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mongodb mongodb    0 Nov  7 17:29 mongod.lock*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mongodb mongodb  20K Nov  7 17:29 sizeStorer.wt*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mongodb mongodb  114 Nov  7 17:29 storage.bson*

dutzi in dutzipc in ~
❯ sudo -H -u mongodb bash -c 'touch /media/dutzi/hdd/mongodb/asdasd'
touch: cannot touch '/media/dutzi/hdd/mongodb/asdasd': Permission denied
```

Comment: Seems something changed on mounted disk. can you please share output of  **ls -ld /media/dutzi/hdd/mongodb** and **ls -ld /media/dutzi/hdd**

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure one of these will work, but let me know in comments:

- Check the permissions under the remaining directories

  - journal, diagnostics.data

Most of the DB seems empty, if that's the case, and previous idea doesn't resolve, then:

- Wipe it out and start from scratch.

---

You don't need those files to be executable. I believe 444 is enough.